# Bootstrap 3 - Month Calendar inside grid column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar

I need embeding a calendar months, inside of column grid  bootstrap. There are some libreries for make it? (if is posible, must to be customizable)

Thanks, Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```html
<table width="676" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://d227d4nygip7u.cloudfront.net/pms/graphics/compucom/reimagine-email-banner.jpg" width="676" height="200" style="width:676px;height:200px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding:15px 30px;">
            <p style="color:#666666;line-height:25px;">Welcome to the <a href="http://www.compucom.com/fall-2015-ezine" style="color:#0068D9;">inaugural issue of <b><i style="color:#0068D9;">#reimagine</i></b>,</a> CompuCom's IT and business transformation e-zine. Why an e-zine? Because you have IT and business challenges and opportunities you need to address, and we have ideas, insights and best practices that we'd like to share.</p>
            <p style="color:#666666;line-height:25px;">Our Fall 2015 issue focuses on IT walk-up service centers &mdash; a new support option that organizations are embracing in a big way. We believe IT walk-up service centers will transform not only hot IT delivers support to end users, but also how end users perceive the role of IT in their daily lives.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding:15px 30px;">
            <h2 style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;color:#323232;font-weight:300;">In this issue, you can:</h2>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-right:20px;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p valign="top" style="line-height: 50%;color:#FF0000;font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;">&rsaquo;</p>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p style="color:#666666;margin-top:0;">Explore how walk-up services create value, including tips for making walk-up services successful in your organization.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p valign="top" style="line-height: 50%;color:#FF0000;font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;">&rsaquo;</p>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p style="color:#666666;line-height:18px;margin-top:0;">Learn about the IT and business trends driving walk-up service centers.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p valign="top" style="line-height: 50%;color:#FF0000;font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;">&rsaquo;</p>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p style="color:#666666;line-height:18px;margin-top:0;">Discover how walk-up services can better support the technology demands of today's multi-generational workforce.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p style="line-height: 50%;color:#FF0000;font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;">&rsaquo;</p>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p style="color:#666666;line-height:18px;margin:0">Gain insights from CompuCom expert Steve Pike as he explores the nexus of mobile technology and walk-up services.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                    <p style="line-height: 50%;color:#FF0000;font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;">&rsaquo;</p>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-bottom:20px;vertical-align: top;">
                                    <p style="color:#666666;line-height:18px;margin:0;">See real-world results from a market leader that has implemented multiple walk-up service centers.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <img src="http://d227d4nygip7u.cloudfront.net/pms/graphics/compucom/fall-2015-ezine.jpg" width="170" height="220" style="width:170px;height:220px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding:15px 30px;">
            <p style="color:#666666;line-height:25px;">I hope you enjoy this first issue of <a href="http://www.compucom.com/fall-2015-ezine;color:#328CAF;"><b><i style="color:#0068D9;">#reimagine</i></b></a>. Future issues will cover a wide range of technology topics certain to resonate with you. If you'd like to share feedback or offer suggestions on topics you'd like to see addressed in future issues, I'm just a click away.</p>
            <p style="color:#666666;">Regards,</p>
            <p style="font-weight:bold;color:#666666;margin:0;">Jonathan James | <span style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none;">CompuCom</span></p>
            <p style="color:#666666;margin:0;">Chief Marketing Officer</p>
            <p style="color:#666666;margin:0;"><a href="mailto:jonathan.james@compucom.com" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none;">Jonathan.James@compucom.com</a></p>
            <p style="color:#666666;margin:0 0 15px;"><a href="http://compucom.com" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none;">www.CompuCom.com</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="560" height="40" style="width:560px;height:40px;background:#323232;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/CompuComSystems">
                            <img width="19" height="18" style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:19px;height:18px;" src="http://d227d4nygip7u.cloudfront.net/pms/graphics/compucom/allyimg-facebook_icon.png">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/compucom" style="border:none;">
                            <img width="19" height="18" style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:19px;height:18px;" src="http://d227d4nygip7u.cloudfront.net/pms/graphics/compucom/allyimg-lnkedin_icon.png">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/CompuCom" style="border:none;">
                            <img width="19" height="18" style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:19px;height:18px;" src="http://d227d4nygip7u.cloudfront.net/pms/graphics/compucom/allyimg-twitter_icon.png">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/LeadingITSpecialist" style="border:none;">
                            <img width="18" height="18" style="border:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:18px;height:18px;" src="http://d227d4nygip7u.cloudfront.net/pms/graphics/compucom/YouTube_18x18.png">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:15px 30px; line-height:14px;color:#666666;font-size:10px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial;">
            <p>Copyright 2015 CompuCom Systems, Inc., 7171 Forest Lane, Dallas, TX 75230. All rights reserved. CompuCom is a registered trademark of CompuCom Systems, Inc. All trademarks and trade names mentioned herein are the property of their respective owners in the United States, Canada, and/or other countries. <a style="color:#518287;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.compucom.com/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:15px 30px 30px; line-height:14px;color:#666666;font-size:10px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial;">
            <p>UNSUBSCRIBE - If you would prefer not to receive any electronic communications from CompuCom, click the unsubscribe button at the bottom of this email. This email is served by a reputable third party at CompuCom's request.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I resolved the problem in this web:
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Thanks,